# tax_query: What to pass when I want to have all terms?

Tags: taxonomy, terms, tax-query

…

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wr_event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => $order,
    'meta_value' => $yesterday,
    'meta_compare' => $compare,
    if ( is_null($cat) )
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'event_type',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => $cat,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
                ),
           )
);
```

I'm confused, what do I pass in order to get all posts from all terms?
Right now I can for instance pass `sports` in order to get all sports-events, but how do I get all events? I know I could just get rid of the `tax_query()` however I'm using this as a param, where I can pass along a certain tax or if not, i want all posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply omit (or not add) `tax_query` part  of arguments.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wr_event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => $order,
    'meta_value' => $yesterday,
    'meta_compare' => $compare,
);

if ( ! is_null($cat) )
  $args['tax_query'] =array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'event_type',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => $cat,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
                ),
           );
```

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP, which wants to query all posts that are assigned a term in a given taxonomy, without explicitly specifying all terms in that taxonomy.

Comment: @ChipBennett not clear, it does say that getting rid of it is acceptable, OP can always clarify :)

Comment: Your method is correct (only adding the `tax_query` conditionally), but the underlying question - how to get all posts in a certain taxonomy is the meat of the question. :)

Comment: Thank you, updated my question … I get the following error if I do this … `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')' `

Comment: @mathiregister this is pseudo-code, you need to adapt logic to your actual code

Comment: But since I'm not that much of a programmer I'd love to see some actual code :) So how do I do that? If my param `$cat` is set to `NULL` I don't want my `tax_query` to happen.